# Can't connect to mobile internet on iPhone 4s

Tags: iphone, cellular-data

The other day I noticed my mobile Internet was not working on my iPhone 4s. I thought I had used it all up.

Turns out I have 1 GB of data, so why is it not allowing me to access the Internet?

I have tried rebooting/restarting phone, resetting Internet settings, turning phone off and on, and still nothing works. I can't seem to find Cellular Mobile Data/Mobile Network Data! I am currently on the EE network.

Comment: did you call your provider ?

Comment: Ring EE. Tell them your problem, get them to send you a new 'setup' file. You just need to OK it when it arrives.

Answer (score 1):

For American iPhones, go into Settings, then in the first group of settings there should be a Cellular tab. Click this and you will be presented with a list of options to do with Mobile Data and Data Roaming.

If this tab is not present, it may also be called Mobile Data or may be located inside of the Phone tab.

If the tab is not located in any of these places, please contact your mobile phone operator for network specific instructions that may apply.